# Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS USB drive not working

Tags: 18.04, usb, mount, hard-drive

I am new to ubuntu. I plug in my usb harddrive, but that harddrive didn't show in files > other locations area. Where can I open my usb hardriver?

I looked at disk and I do see my USB drive under `/dev/sdd1`. But when I try to go there it said it isn't a directory. I have a screenshot below:

[image: Disks]

I tried to use the  following command:

```
mount -t auto /dev/sdd1 /media/usb-drive
```

But it gave me the following error.

> mount: only root can use "--types" option

What should I do next?

@heynnema
the following are the screen shots. Thanks.
[image]
[image]
Sincerely,
the0101

Comment: Try `sudo mkdir /media/usb_drive` then `sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /media/usb_drive` then go to `/media/usb_drive` to access your USB.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Raffa. After that command I got the following error. "mount: /media/usb_drive: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error."

Comment: Do you have the `ntfs-3g` package installed? `sudo apt install ntfs-3g`

Comment: @C.S.Cameron **WHY** would you tell the user to **FORMAT** the partition?

Comment: Reconnect the drive to a Windows machine and run `chkdsk` on it. Then retry.

Comment: @muru Thank you for for reply. I tried to install the ntfs-3g package. Seems like I already have it. 
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
[sudo] password for the0101: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ntfs-3g is already the newest version (1:2017.3.23-2ubuntu0.18.04.2).
ntfs-3g set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfwup1 libwayland-egl1-mesa
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

Comment: @heynnema I tried chkdsk on it with a windows machine. And it is fine in window. But doesn't work for my ubuntu.

Comment: Try `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdd1 /media/usb-drive`

Comment: @heynnema I tried that and it have the following error. 
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdd1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Comment: @the0101 We'll do a little more digging, but you may have to backup your files using Windows, then re-init the drive. Start the `Disks` app again, select the disk, go to the "hamburger" icon and select SMART Data & Tests, edit your question with screenshot(s) of the SMART Data. Then start the `gparted` app, and set it to view /dev/sdd, and take a screenshot of that too. Let me know when that's done.